# redirecting user to individual home page using laravel not the same home page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

please I need you to assist I have followed the book tutorial from the beginning but what I need is for users to be able to login to individual profile for example User-A can only access his document or work on a particular table not the same table as everyone.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what is the problem your having, and what code are you using?

Comment: you should be able to use the same table etc but utilise say a user_id field, that then you can use a relationship with that user, this way if the tables you want all have the same data then your not creating a new table for each user etc.

Comment: Do you have some code? Try to relate your documents table with your user table and then use a filter to check if the user has or not permissions over the document

Comment: I have 4 tables called Table A, Table B, Table C and Table D so if a user A log in  I want him to see all record on Table A and edit base on Table A alone , If user B log in I want him to see all record on Table B and edit base table B e.t.c but am using laravel 5.2 to design please assit I have successfully created the view for CRUD but just to redirect each user to particular table and lastly and administrator should be able to work on all tables